# Executing openssl command using Java runtime

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, exec

I am trying to execute the openssl command for encryption. I am trying to launch the `openssl` via java runtime.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ExecuteShellCommand {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecuteShellCommand obj = new ExecuteShellCommand();

    String command="echo \'StringtoEncrypt\' | \\openssl enc -a -e -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -pass pass:mySecretPass |\\openssl enc -a -d -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -pass pass:mySecretPass";

    String output = obj.executeCommand(command);        

    System.out.println(output);
}

private String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();
}}
```

When this class runs it just runs the `echo 'StringtoEncrypt' | \openssl enc -a -e -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -pass pass:mySecretPass |\openssl enc -a -d -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -pass pass:mySecretPass`.

It doesn't execute the `openssl`. Looks like only the echo part is getting executed but not the `openssl`.  The command works well when I execute it in the console.

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to just do that (the encryption) in java?

Comment: Artjom B. What do you mean by lot more required here? I just approved all the edits done by @User0123456789

Comment: @jtahlborn Java just allows AES with 128 bytes. Whereas I need 256 bytes.  in order to do that in java i need to update the JRE security directory with couple of  policy  jars.  We dont want to update the JRE, so exploring other options.

Comment: what about bouncycastle?

Comment: @GAK I have to agree with you, there wasn't a lot required